# Convert Key to VirtualKeyCode

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, keyboard-events

In my C#/WPF/.NET 4.5 application I am trying to capture a key press via a KeyEventHandler, and later use the excellent [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) to emulate that key press (to map gesture, voice etc. commands to a keyboard).

The trouble is, I get a member of the `Key` enumeration from the `KeyEventHandler`'s `RoutedEventArgs`, but later I need to pass a `VirtualKeyCode` to `SimulateKeyPress()`.

How do I go from `Key` to `VirtualKeyCode`?

```
// Trigger reader
private void Editor_CommandButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  PressKeyModal.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
  AddHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)Editor_HandleKeyDownEvent);
}
// Read key press from keyboard
private void Editor_HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  // Here is the culprit
  VirtualKeyCode CodeOfKeyToEmulate = ConvertSomehow(e.Key);
  // /culprit
  PressKeyModal.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
  RemoveHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)Editor_HandleKeyDownEvent);
}

// Later, emulate the key press
private void EmulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode codeOfKeyToEmulate( {
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(codeOfKeyToEmulate);
}
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .NET 4.5 (edited question accordingly)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey.aspx) method is what I was looking for. The troublesome section in the code above thus becomes:

```
// Read key press from keyboard
private void Editor_HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  // The rehabilitated culprit
  VirtualKeyCode CodeOfKeyToEmulate = (VirtualKeyCode)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key);
  // /rehabilitated culprit
  PressKeyModal.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
  RemoveHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)Editor_HandleKeyDownEvent);
}
```

It's worth noting that the `KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey` method returns not a `VirtualKeyCode` but an `int32` which has to be cast into a `VirtualKeyCode`.

Comment: Thanks to @keyboardP for his answer. He had originally suggested the [KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.keyfromvirtualkey.aspx) method, which was not what I was looking for, but he steered me to the right direction (the [KeyInterop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.aspx) class).

Comment: Copied the wrong link from the MSDN page but glad you got it sorted. Don't forget to accept your answer in a couple of days :)

Comment: @keyboardP I would have accepted your second answer if it were still there =) Thanks a lot for the help.